# Creation of an AsyncButton in a React App - Update button state in an async function while the component is unmount

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a React app with multiple views. In a view I have a button that performs an async task when it is clicked. Also when the button is clicked it changes its state, in order to show a spinner instead of the default text. When the task is completed the state change back to to the default text. I also hold the state of the button to the sessionStorage.

Here is a snippet of the view:

```
////Set initial state
const [state, setState] = useState(()=>{
  if(getFromMemory('asyncState')) return getFromMemory('asyncState')
  else return false
})

///Click handler
const onClick = async () => {
  setState(true); 
  storeInMemory({ asyncState: true });
  await props.asyncTask();
  setState(false);
  storeInMemory({ asyncState: false });
};
```

If the view is changed during the async task and the component unmounts, when the component mounts again (because the user choose to go back to this view), I set the initial state of the button that performs the async task according to the value that is stored in the sessionStorage.

However when the async task is over, the state does not update back to the default state, but it is still a spinner.

I am suspecting that the updates of the state are merged or the last setState of the onClick function does not works because the component unmounts.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks really prone to race conditions, and I would consider subscribing your localStorage to your local state update in a useEffect() to solve the issue from the root, being that the final goal.
Also consider that the async task could fail, and probably you still want to unset the loading state.

It could look something like

```js
////Set initial state
const [state, setState] = useState(Boolean(getFromMemory('asyncState')))

useEffect(() => {
  storeInMemory({ asyncState: state })
}, [state])

///Click handler
const onClick = async () => {
  setState(true); 
  try {
    await props.asyncTask();
  } finally {
    setState(false); // You probably want this to happen anyway
  }  
};
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with your corrections butb the problem still remains. I beleive that react remove the setState in the finally block when the component is unmount.

Comment: While it's true that React does batch state updates, it sounds like your `asyncTask` is somehow unmounting your component, which leads me to think that the hierarchy structure of your components is not ideal. If you must for some reason hide your button while the task is running, consider returning `null` in that component instead of using conditional rendering in the parent (as this triggers mounts/unmounts). Can't say much more without further context - hopefully this is still helpful